# Data of TreeMap is strangly changed

Tags: java, excel, database, collections, apache-poi

my program exports a table of a database to excel. The last days with no code changed in the methods that belong to that export it worked, but today it does not work anymore. I tested how far the data was correctly saved and when it was not anymore, but the problem is that i did not do anything between that to lines, that should change the values. In my DefaultTableModel the data is correct and every line of the table is saved but in the map then the amount of data is correct but every row of the map is the last row of the TableModel.

```
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet();

    TreeMap<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
    Object[] arr = new Object[dm.getColumnCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = dm.getColumnName(i);
    }

    data.put("-1", arr);

    arr = new Object[dm.getColumnCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i < dm.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = dm.getValueAt(i, j);
            //arr[j] here is the value as it should be 
        }
        data.put(Integer.toString(i), arr);
    }

    Set<String> ids = data.keySet();
    XSSFRow row;
    int rowID = 0;


    for (String key : ids)
    {
        row = ws.createRow(rowID++);

        Object[] values = data.get(key);

        int cellID = 0;

        for (Object o : values)
        {
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellID++);
            cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
            //o.toString() is the wrong value 
        }
    }
```

correct Data:

1 | a | b

2 | c | d

3 | e | f

4 | g | h

wrong Data:

1 | a | b

1 | a | b

1 | a | b

1 | a | b

Data is only for showing purpose

Comment: Please show the output from printing the map, e.g. `System.out.println(data)`.

Comment: I can see that you are putting the same `arr` for many keys. Reallocate the array on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy Turner mentioned in the comment, you need to allocate a new array for each new row. Otherwise, you are overwriting values in each iteration.

The code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dm.getRowCount(); i++)
{
    // reallocate the array
    arr = new Object[dm.getColumnCount()];
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
    {
        arr[j] = dm.getValueAt(i, j);
        //arr[j] here is the value as it should be 
    }
    data.put(Integer.toString(i), arr);
}
```

Comment: thank u, i think i made mistakes when i copied the method, but another weird thing since i outsources the method to an external class that the data is not ordered anymore, but it should be because the database of course returns the data in correct order in reference to the id.

Comment: You are welcome! This is a tricky code that saves column names in the map at the row with -1 index. Be careful!